# *Excel* reference cell to increase by 1 every 6th cell, Cant figure this out for the life of me :(

Tags: excel

Autofill is messing me up here, i currently have this in Column A:

```
A1 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A4))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A2 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A4))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A3 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A4))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A4 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A4))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A5 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A4))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A6 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A4))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A7 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A5))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A8 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A5))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A9 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A5))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A10 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A5))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A11 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A5))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A12 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A5))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
```

And i need to repeat this for 20,000 cells where the same formula is repeated 20,000 times but the reference number increases by 1 every 6 cells. But when i highlight all 12 rows and autofill it i get something like this:

```
A1 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A4))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A2 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A4))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A3 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A4))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A4 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A4))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A5 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A4))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A6 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A4))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A7 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A5))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A8 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A5))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A9 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A5))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A10 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A5))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A11 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A5))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A12 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A5))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A13 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A13))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A14 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A13))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A15 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A13))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A16 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A13))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A17 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A13))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A18 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A13))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A19 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A19))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A20 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A19))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A21 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A19))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A22 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A19))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A23 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A19))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
A24 =IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A19))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
```

Instead of my reference # (A!$A#) increasing by 1 every time from 4 to 5 to 6 to 7 it increases by 6 every single time. Please help me, ive been stuck on this all day and there is no way i can manually do this for 20,000 cells :(

Comment: Have you tried `INDIRECT()` using `ROW()+3` instead of  `$A4`? Problem is that `ROW()` will cause a performance hit with such a large range.

Comment: @bugdrown I'm unfamiliar with INDIRECT() and ROW() so i wouldn't know how to use them for this problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a simple and stupid solution that will make the job, but for sure there's some right way to do it.

Create a column with numbers that would be correct for you, autofill till the end, numbers will increase by one as you need. (Decrease decimals if needed)

```
M
_
4
4
4
4
4
4
5
5
5
5
5
5
6
6
6
6
6
6
```

After that just use `INDIRECT`

In my case column M contains those numbers. In this way you'll create references to cells dynamically with values from this column.

```
=IF((money!$G$7-(INDIRECT("A!$A"&M1)))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )
```

Comment: I can't have any other columns that contain data on this sheet, could i do this same thing with a column from another excel sheet? so that it's something like this: =IF((money!$G$7-(INDIRECT("A!$A"&excelsheetname!M1)))>=0, 'C'!$B$4, "" )? @hiichaki

Comment: yes, of course, it can be any other worksheet

Answer (score 0):

In cell A1, enter:

```
 =INDIRECT("IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A$"& 
 (ROW(OFFSET(B1,6-MOD(ROW(),6),0))-2)&"))>=0, 
 'C'!$B$4, "")")
```

In cell A2, enter the same formula:

```
 =INDIRECT("IF((money!$G$7-(A!$A$"& 
 (ROW(OFFSET(B1,6-MOD(ROW(),6),0))-2)&"))>=0, 
 'C'!$B$4, "")")
```

and then copy cell A2 and paste it in the remaining cells, A3 through A20000.